# Best way to split table every day

Tags: mysql

I have a table collecting huge virtual machine cluster statistics every day, I want to deposit old stats in tables named with their creation date everyday to improve query performance.

Two possible ways I thought:

1. - at 00:00 every day, rename table `stat_cpu` to `stat_cpu_(yesterday date)`
   - create `stat_cpu`

pros: efficient

cons: there are data inserting during this procedure, application needs to be rewritten to prevent inserting failure.

2. - at 00:00 every day, create `stat_cpu_(yesterday date)`
   - move yesterday's data to `stat_cpu_(yesterday date)`

pros: application doesn't need to be changed

cons: huge data transfer

Which way is better? Or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Did you try partitioning? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: partitioning have certain pitfalls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should combine your methods i guess

```
CREATE TABLE `stat_cpu_last_day` LIKE `stat_cpu`;

INSERT INTO `stat_cpu_last_day` (
    SELECT * FROM `stat_cpu`
);

RENAME TABLE
    `stat_cpu_last_day` TO `ghost_table`,
    `stat_cpu` TO `stat_cpu_last_day`,
    `ghost_table` TO `stat_cpu`
;
```

if you will do it this way, data inserting during this procedure will not be lost.

Because only place here it can happen its `RENAME` query its fast and locks the tables it uses.

You dont need to rewrite you app.

About huge data transfer in INSERT query... alot of indexes? (you can remove them before insertion) it will be fast anyway. But even no matter.

This action should be scheduled